# c - how gets() work after scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, gets

I have two questions:

1. why only when i do space in "%d " --> `scanf("%d ", &num);` it works?

I tried `fflush(stdin) \ _flushall()` between the scnaf and the gets and it doesn't works, it skips the gets.

2. When I do the space, it first does scanf then the gets and after that it print the number and print the string.

```
void main()
{
    char ch, str[10];
    int num;
    printf("Enter your number : ");
    scanf("%d ", &num);
    printf("%d\n",num);
    gets(str);
    puts(str);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d ", &num);` does not return until non-white space is entered after the number.

Comment: Do not *ever* use gets.  You shouldn't worry about how it interacts with `scanf`, because you should *never* use it.

Comment: Also do not use `fflush(stdin)`

Comment: Perhaps it might be useful to read the manual pages

Comment: There's **no** `gets()` function in C. `main` must return `int`.

Comment: When saying "it works" and "it doesn't work", please provide the exact input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: The C FAQ covers all these problems with `scanf`. See [*Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?*](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and associated entries.

Comment: @n.m. "*7.19.7.7 The gets function*" unless you're subtly pointing out it's dangerous to use which newbies aren't going to understand. `void main` is technically correct because the standard allows for `main` to be defined "*in some other implementation-defined manner.*", though it's not a good idea.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour and ther is no standard function `_flushall`.

Comment: @Schwern: [7.19 is about `stddef.h`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19) which does not cover stream I/O. What are you refering to?

Comment: @Olaf ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 and ISO/IEC 9899:201x is what I have available. The numbers might have drifted. Yes technically `gets` was removed in C11, but it's not about being technically correct, it's about communicating to a newbie.

Comment: Concerning `main()`, C11 5.1.2.2.1 1 has "It (`main`) shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters: ... or with two parameters... or equivalent;  or in some other implementation-defined manner".

Comment: @Schwern: Those are not the standard. While technically also not the standard, n1570 as the final draft is exactly the same as he standard, except for two irrrelevant changed predefined macros. And that does not include `gets`, except for the foreword where it is very clear about it having been removed.

Comment: @chux: While agree with you, I've given up as the full section is indeed unclear about what exactly "or in some other implementation-defined manner" refers to exactly: the full declaration, declarator only or just the "It shall be defined" part. But you are right that e.g. POSIX requires the two listed variants (plus an extra optional argument, IIRC).

Comment: @Olaf True there is potential ambiguity in "some other implementation-defined manner" referring to 1) the parameters or 2) the parameters and return type.  IAC, OP is evidently able to compile with `void main()` and the key issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @chux: AFIAK only Windows as a full-size OS allows `void main…`. The others are POSIX compliant, not allowing that. The compiler not warning is - as I'm sure you know - needs not warn, though. And for freestanding implemtations this section does not apply at all.

Comment: @Schwern Update your copy. "This third edition cancels and replaces \[...] Major changes from the previous edition include: \[...] removed the gets function". *void main is technically correct* yes, but it's not *right*.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714). It has been removed since C99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. why only when i do space in "%d " --> scanf("%d ", &num); it works?

`scanf("%d", &num);` without a space after the `"%d"`, stops scanning after reading a number.  So with input <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `'\n'` remains in `stdin` for the next input function like the now non-standard `gets()`.  `gets()` reads that single `'\n'` and returns.  By adding a space, `scanf("%d ", &num);` consumes the white-space after the number and does not return until non-white-scape is entered after the number.

> 2. When I do the space, it first does scanf then the gets and after that it print the number and print the string.

By adding a space, `scanf("%d ", &num);` does not return until non-white-space is entered after the number (as in `'a'` in the following).  Since `stdin` is usually line buffered, this means input of 2 lines needs to first occur. <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Recommend to instead use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input.

```
char str[10*2]; // no need for such a small buffer
int num;
printf("Enter your number : ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
sscanf(str, "%d", &num);
printf("%d\n",num);

printf("Enter data : ");
fflush(stdout);
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
fputs(str, stdout);
```

More robust code would check the results of `fgets(), sscanf()` and use `strtol()` rather than `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

The C FAQ covers all these problems with `scanf`. See [*Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?*](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and associated entries. Generally you'll use `fgets` followed by processing the resulting line such as with `sscanf` and checking that `sscanf` succeeded. This avoids leaving unparsed input and risking an infinite loop.

```
int number;
char line[255];

fgets( line, sizeof(line), stdin );
if( sscanf( line, "%d", &number ) != 1 ) {
    fputs("That doesn't look like a number.\n", stdin);
}
```

Note that `fgets` will read to a newline *or as much as your buffer can hold*. If the line is larger than your buffer, it might only read part of the line. Next read from input will get the rest of the line. There's ways to avoid this, such as [the POSIX getline function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), but at least you don't wind up in an infinite loop.

Let's decipher some comments.

### Do not ever use `gets`. Use `fgets`.

The reason you don't use `gets` is because there's no way to limit how much is read from `stdin`. This means the user can overflow the buffer causing havoc.

```
char buffer[32];

// What the line is more than 31 characters?
gets(buffer);
```

`fgets()` takes the size of the buffer and will read that many characters at most. This prevents a buffer overflow.

```
char buffer[32];

// If there's more than 31 characters it will stop reading.
// The next read of stdin will get the rest of the line.
fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
```

### "*There's no `gets()` function in C.*"

Yes, there *is* a `gets()` function in C.

Yes, there *isn't* a `gets()` function in C.

It depends on which C you're talking about.

Some people when they say "C" mean C11, the current standard. Others when they say "C" mean C99 the previous standard. Some still adhere to C90, the original standard. There is a `gets()` function in C90. It was deprecated in C99. It was removed from the language in C11.

C compilers and documentation lag very, very, very far behind the standard. Many are still working on full support of C99. If you work to C11 you're going to be very surprised by the lack of support. If you want your code to work on most any compiler, write to C99.

Anyway, don't use `gets`.

Comment: The question is tagged without any specific version, so we have to assume standard C, which is **only** C11 - just read the tag-wiki! If you consider this significant, the correct way would be to ask OP for clarification.

Comment: @Olaf A person asking basic questions about `scanf` probably doesn't even know C11 or the C standard exist. If you're technically correct, but the person asking the question doesn't understand, what's the point? Who are you talking to?

Comment: "C compilers and documentation lag very, very, very far behind the standard." - Of the high-end compilers for full-OS hosted environments,  only MSVC is lagging behind - since at least 18 years. gcc and clang are fine, together with most relevant parts of the libraries (they are not part of those two compilers, btw).

Comment: @Olaf A lot of people use MSVC, unfortunately. Or learn on out of date compilers using out of date material. If they're asking about `scanf` and `gets`, they're probably one of those people.